# How to apend AJAX for multi- select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

This is my working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/rkep92vo/

My AJAX:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/kpiDetailsList",
    datatype: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      'employee_id': employee_id,
      }),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      var parsed_data = data;
      monthly_list = parsed_data.monthly_list;
      monthly_list_name = parsed_data.monthly_list_name;
      quarterly_list = parsed_data.quarterly_list;
      quarterly_list_name = parsed_data.quarterly_list_name;
      console.log(monthly_list.length)
      console.log(quarterly_list.length)

      if(monthly_list.length != 0 || quarterly_list.length != 0) {
      console.log('inside first if')
      $('#list1').css('pointer-events','');
      $("#span_month").attr("title", "");
      $('#list1_items').empty();
          for (index = 0; index < monthly_list.length; index++) {
            for (index = 0; index < monthly_list_name.length; index++) {
            $('#list1_items').append("<li><input type='checkbox' name='month' value='" + monthly_list[index] + "'id='" + monthly_list[index] + "'><label for='" + monthly_list[index] + "'>" + monthly_list_name[index] + "</label></li>");
            }
        }
      $('#list2').css('pointer-events','');
      $("#span_quarter").attr("title", "");
      $('#list2_items').empty();
          for (index = 0; index < quarterly_list.length; index++) {
            for (index = 0; index < quarterly_list.length; index++) {
            $("#list2_items").append("<option name='quarter' value='"+ quarterly_list[index] +"' id='" + quarterly_list[index] + "'>"+ quarterly_list_name[index] + "</option>");
            }
          }
        }
```

With this AJAX it is calling, but the value is not being shown.
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p16B.png)As you can see in the console here, in the working JS Fiddle, the value is shown but in the `.append(<option>)`the value is not being shown.
If someone can please help me out, Im new to this.

Thank you.

Comment: You've done the first step and used a code snippet to demonstrate your issue. Now go the second step and make the code snippet actually work. Currently it throws an error.

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to reduce your code to the relevant bits. There's quite a lot of fluff in there that has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: I made the changes, thankyou, but due to the issue the code isnt working

Comment: The code snippet still throws errors when I try to run it. Also I really meant it: Reduce the amount of your code. Remove everything that does not *directly* have to do with your question. This very likely means you need to re-write your sample code from scratch.

Comment: Done, I added the working example as well as reduced the code, now please have a look and let me know if there's a way

Answer (score 0):

Try to post a request as synchronous call.  After It work, then you can change it asynchronous call.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType,
  async:false                  // ****** synchronous call
});
```